# Unable to connect to remote databases from server explorer, sql server 2008 r2 management studio and others

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, server-explorer

After uninstalling vs2011 beta, I cannot connect to remote databases from server explorer in vs2010 and even from sql server 2008 r2 management studio.

the error message from server explorer in vs2010 is as follow:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

the error message from sql server 2008 r2 management studio is as follow:

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx,xxxx\SQL2008.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=10060&LinkId=20476

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that's not because of the vs2011 beta uninstallation, that is becuase the TCP port 1434 was close where I use Internet. by opening the 1434 port the problem solved.